# Nodejs, close mongo db connection via callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

I have the problem with callbacks, async thinking etc.

Execution program:

> 1. Connect to mongoDb.
> 2. Create url - https://example.com + add part from locArray.
> 3. Send get request (for each).
> 4. Save data to mongo db.
> 5. Close connection.

Problem:

- If the connection was closed on last line in jsonDataFromApi - "server instance pool was destroyed" before all data from each request was saved to db
- So `callback(db)` was sent to another place - `closeMongoDb`
- but error was appeared

  > "Cannot read property 'close' of undefined".

I think, the problem is with async, send callbacks etc.

```
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        const Array = require('node-array');
        const request = require('request');

        var locationArray = [
          'location1',
          'location2',
          'location3',
          'location4'
        ];

        var dataFromLocApi = (loc, callback) => {
          request({
            url: `https://example.com/${loc}`,
            json: true
          }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error){
            callback('Error connection to url.');
            } else{
            callback(undefined, body.result);
          }
         });
        };

        var jsonDataFromApi = (urldb, callback) => {
        MongoClient.connect(urldb, (err, db) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('MongoDb connection error.');
          }
          console.log('MongoDb - connected.');
          locationArray.forEachAsync(function(loc, index, arr) {
            dataFromLocApi(loc, (errorMessage, results) => {
              if (errorMessage) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
              } else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 2));
                db.collection('testCollection').insert(results, function(error, record) {
                  if (error)
                    throw error;
                  console.log("data saved");
                });
              }
            });

          }, function() {
            console.log('complete');
          });
        callback(db);
        });
        }

var closeMongoDb = (urldb, callback) => {
    jsonDataFromApi(urldb, (error, db) => {
      if (error){
        callback('Close connection - failure');
      } else{
        db.close();
        console.log('MongoDb connections was closed.');
    }
    });
    }

    closeMongoDb('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDb', (err, db) => {

      console.log('DONE');
    } );
```

Comment: Can you please also paste code of function `closeMongoDb`?

Comment: It is all code, the closeMongoDb is not a function.

Comment: What is it then?

Comment: I would like to start the script. So I should create closeMongoDb function and run it like on my example code?

Comment: At the end of `jsonDataFromApi`, you provide `db` to callback as first argument. But in the `closeMongoDb` call, the callback takes `db` as the second parameter.

Comment: If I send only db - closeMongoDb('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDb', (db) =>{.... also "server instance pool was destroyed.".

Comment: @ Akshendra Pratap - closeMondoDb definition was created. Code is running, but database does not close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely a problem with asynchrony there.
You're not waiting for the items to be processed before calling the `db.close()`.

Also, the functions that you have defined have the unclear semantics. For example, the function `closeMongoDb` should basically close the DB and that's it. But here does the other job: fetches the data and closes the DB afterwards.

Also, I'd probably use the `async` module instead of `node-array` as the last one seems to solve other problem.

I've refactored the code. Please read my comments. I tried to make it as clear as possible.

```js
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const request = require("request");
// We are going to use the async module
// This is a classical module to handle async behavior.
const async = require("async");

// As you can see this function accepts a callback
// If there is an error connecting to the DB
// it passes it up to the caller via callback(err)
// This is a general pattern
const connectToDb = function(urldb, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(urldb, (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("MongoDb connection error.");
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        // If everything is OK, pass the db as a data to the caller.
        callback(undefined, db);
    });
};

// This method fetches the data for a single location.
// The logic with errors/data is absolutely the same.
const getData = (loc, callback) => {
    request(
        {
            url: `https://example.com/${loc}`,
            json: true
        },
        (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                callback("Error connection to url.");
                return;
            }

            callback(undefined, body.result);
        }
    );
};

// This function goes over each location, pulls the data and saves it to the DB
// Last parameter is a callback, I called it allDataFetchedCb to make it clear
// that we are calling it after ALL the locations have been processed
// And everything is saved to the DB.
const saveDataFromLocations = function(locations, db, allDataFetchedCb) {
    // First param here is an array of items
    // The second one is an async function that we want to execute for each item
    // When a single item is processed we call the callback. I named it 'locProcessedCB'
    // So it's clear what happens.
    // The third parameter is a callback that is going to be called when ALL the items
    // have been processed.
    async.each(
        locations,
        function(loc, locProcessedCb) {
            getData(loc, (apiErr, results) => {
                if (apiErr) {
                    console.log(apiErr);
                    // Well, we couldn't process the item, pass the error up.
                    locProcessedCb(apiErr);
                    return;
                }

                console.log(
                    `Obtained the data from the api: ${JSON.stringify(
                        results,
                        undefined,
                        2
                    )}`
                );

                db.collection("testCollection").insert(results, function(dbError) {
                    if (dbError) {
                        // Also an error, we couldn't process the item.
                        locProcessedCb(dbError);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Ok the item is processed without errors, after calling this
                    // So we tell the async.each function: ok, good, go on and process the next one.
                    locProcessedCb();
                });
            });
        },
        function(err) {
            // We gonna get here after all the items have been processed or any error happened.
            if (err) {
                allDataFetchedCb(err);
                return;
            }

            console.log("All the locations have been processed.");

            // All good, passing the db object up.
            allDataFetchedCb(undefined, db);
        }
    );
};

// This function is an entry point.
// It calls all the above functions one by one.
const getDataAndCloseDb = function(urldb, locations, callback) {
    //Well, let's connect.
    connectToDb(urldb, (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        // Now let's get everything.
        saveDataFromLocations(locations, db, (err, db) => {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return;
            }

            // If somehow there is no db object, or no close method we wanna know about it.
            if (!db || !db.close) {
                callback(new Error("Unable to close the DB Connection."));
            }

            // Closing the DB.
            db.close(err => {
                // If there's no error err === undefined or null
                // So this call is equal to callback(undefined);
                callback(err);
            });
        });
    });
};

const locationArray = ["location1", "location2", "location3", "location4"];

// Finally calling the function, passing all needed data inside.
getDataAndCloseDb("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDb", locationArray, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(
            `Unable to fetch the data due to the following reason: ${err}`
        );
        return;
    }

    console.log("Done successfully.");
});
```

I didn't run this code as I don't have the URL etc. So please try it yourself and debug if needed.

Comment: Thank You, perfect. Now, I think, I understand the callbacks, create general function. Thank You also for 'async.js'. Very helpful, great description, great lesson for me.

One question, sometimes (according to all resources) we writing
`const getData = (loc, callback) =>`.
But another time:
`const connectToDb = function(urldb, callback)`.

There is a big difference between `cons X = function {}` and `const X = ()=>{}`? If I change it, I think, the behaviour is that same. It is problematic for me, when I should use function, when arrow function `=>`.

Comment: @profiler Here I used arrow functions like `(x) => x * 2` simply as a shorthand for regular `functions`. In fact, there are differences between them. But in this particular case, they'll work exactly the same. You could do  some googling like 'how to use arrow functions'. Or here's the video for you: https://youtu.be/J85lRtO_yjY

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank You for help.